# Why does the developer console not open on old firefox versions?

Tags: firefox

I installed some old firefox versions from v44 to v46 because there is a cool 3D View feature which was removed since v47, and noticed that the developer console does not start.

Does firefox intentionally disable it on older versions in the archive?

https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/44.0/win64/de/

Answer (score 0):

Before installing the version of Firefox you need, delete all the Mozilla folders in your AppData folder. It's a hidden folder in C:\Users{username}.
In my case, I had to delete it in AppData\Local, Appdata\LocalLow and AppData\Roaming.

If you already have Firefox installed, delete it first.

You will know you did it right if while re-installing, it will ask you if you want to transfer data from other browsers.